# ¿Cómo mostrar divs cada cierta cantidad de segundos?

Tags: javascript, html, css, setinterval

Tengo 6 *divs* y necesito mostrarles uno por uno cada 2 segundos.

Sé que es necesario un bucle `for`, para iterar los *divs* y *setInterval* para mostrarlos, pero el problema es que siempre me muestran todos los *divs* al mismo tiempo.

Entonces, el primer `div` se muestra después de 2 segundos, el segundo `div` se muestra debajo del primer `div` también 2 segundos después y así sucesivamente.

Aquí está mi código:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.zoom');

for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    setInterval(() => {
        divs[i].style.display =  'block';  
    }, 2500);

}
```

```css
body{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(28, 146, 210), rgb(242, 252, 254))
}
.zoom {
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .zoom:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
  }

.zoom{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="zoom"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="zoom"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="zoom"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="zoom"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="zoom"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="zoom"></div>

    <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No necesitas el `for` el intervalo ya es un ciclo:

```
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.zoom');

    let i=0;
    let interval = setInterval( () => {
                      divs[i++].style.display = 'block';
                      if(i==divs.length)
                         clearInterval(interval);
                   }, 2500 );
```

Answer (score 4):

Aqui la solucion,

```js
var timeLeft = 10;
var elem = document.getElementById('cuentaDiv');
var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

function countdown() {
    if (timeLeft == -1) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
       
    } else {
      if(timeLeft==8)
      {
         muestraDiv('div1');
      }    
       if(timeLeft==6)
      {
         muestraDiv('div2');
      }    
       if(timeLeft==4)
      {
         muestraDiv('div3');
      }    
       if(timeLeft==2)
      {
         muestraDiv('div4');
      }    
      
      
        elem.innerHTML = timeLeft + ' segundos';
        timeLeft--;
    }
}

function muestraDiv(divId) {
    document.getElementById(divId).style.display =  'block';
}
```

```html
 
<div id="cuentaDiv" >
  
</div>

<div id="div1" style="display:none" >
  Soy div 1
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none" >
Soy div 2
</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none" >
 Soy div 3
</div>
<div id="div4" style="display:none" >
 Soy div 4
</div>
```

Nota: Toma en cuenta que esto se puede mejorar si haces una cuentra ascendente, el nombre del div puede ser 'div'+contador.

saludos.

Comment: Hola Miguel gracias por tu respuesta. Tu solución me funciono muy bien. Ahora lo que quiero es optimizarlo para hacerlo más dinámico. Ejemplo si fuera el supuesto caso de que no fueran 6 Divs si no 1000 Divs. Las sentencias if serían interminables 

Comment: Es sencillo tu secuencia puede ser incremental timeLeft -- por timeLeft ++, y los nombres de los div algo como  ('div' + timeLeft/2) // mostrar div . Pero eso ya te lo propongo de tarea